# How can I detect if the user is scrolling up when the listview has already reached the top

Tags: java, android, listview

How can I test if the user is scrolling up while the `ListView` is already all the way up?

```
answersListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,int scrollState){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view,int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
    int totalItemCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

look at [android-pulltorefresh](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh/blob/master/pulltorefresh/src/com/markupartist/android/widget/PullToRefreshListView.java) , specifically at `onTouchEvent` and on both `onScroll` and 
 `onScrollStateChanged` methods. Basically, you should have `onTouchEvent`